# Archive outlook messages (PST option disabled)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, group-policy

I am looking for a way to archive a year of work emails in an environment where [group-policy](/questions/tagged/group-policy) has disabled `PST` files as per [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/exchange/using-group-policy-to-restrict-the-use-of-pst-files/)

Going forward I will simply delete emails I don't need to store, but I don't want to wade my way through a years worth of received and sent email message by message.

With the `PST` option unavailable, how can I archive outlook messages for future access and search functionality (by author, attachment etc) rather than just dumping them to a folder?

Comment: There isn't another option.  So the best alternative would be to export your mail to a PDF.  Provided you have a PDF plugin within Outlook.  Outside of that there really isn't a solution to archive emails.  What does your IT staff have to say about the matter?

Comment: I've asked the question as the IT staff are operating under policy so they can't provide other options ....... I doubt there *isn't another option* as if I have to I will write code to provide myself with a csv summary of the key details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just export messages to MSG files instead of PST. You can just drag-drop Outlook folders to Windows Explorer or use one of the third-party tools available.

The benefit here is that each Outlook item becomes a separate MSG file. This is much more reliable way to backup Outlook items than a single PST (that can get corrupted easily and you'll loose all data).

Outlook can natively open MSG files, just double-click them in Explorer. With the help of third-party tools you can append additional information to these files (like Sender, Recipients, Subject, etc.) and then search using familiar Windows environment.